# Owned one-to-many field can't be modified all of a sudden - ClassCastException in DatastoreRelationFieldManager.checkForParentSwitch

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, one-to-many, jdo

My web app suddenly won't allow people to buy our products. I don't know what to do.

Last night one of our engineers accidentally removed the `@Persistent` tag from an owned one-to-many field (in the parent class). He uploaded this without testing it to the App Engine server. We got reports that people could not buy things, so we looked at the changes, went in and restored the `@Persistent` tag.

But now we get an exception **every time the code tries to modify that field**.

Please help - I don't know what to do - we've added the `@Persistent` annotation back - why would this exception be happening??

```
@PersistenceCapable
public class Published {
    @Persistent(valueStrategy = IdGeneratorStrategy.IDENTITY)
    @PrimaryKey
    private Long id;

    ...
    // see note about this field above
    @Persistent(defaultFetchGroup = "true", mappedBy = "pub")
    private List<License> licenses;
    ...
}


@PersistenceCapable
public class License {
    @Persistent(valueStrategy = IdGeneratorStrategy.IDENTITY)
    @PrimaryKey
    private Key id;
    @Persistent
    private Published pub;
    ...
}
```

The following exception happens when I create a new Published and call `pub.getLicensed().add(new Licensed(...))`

```
Uncaught exception from servlet
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Long cannot be cast to java.lang.String
    at org.datanucleus.store.appengine.DatastoreRelationFieldManager.checkForParentSwitch(DatastoreRelationFieldManager.java:203)
    at org.datanucleus.store.appengine.DatastoreRelationFieldManager$1.setObjectViaMapping(DatastoreRelationFieldManager.java:134)
    at org.datanucleus.store.appengine.DatastoreRelationFieldManager$1.apply(DatastoreRelationFieldManager.java:113)
    at org.datanucleus.store.appengine.DatastoreRelationFieldManager.storeRelations(DatastoreRelationFieldManager.java:82)
    at org.datanucleus.store.appengine.DatastoreFieldManager.storeRelations(DatastoreFieldManager.java:959)
    at org.datanucleus.store.appengine.DatastorePersistenceHandler.storeRelations(DatastorePersistenceHandler.java:585)
    at org.datanucleus.store.appengine.DatastorePersistenceHandler.insertPostProcess(DatastorePersistenceHandler.java:320)
    at org.datanucleus.store.appengine.DatastorePersistenceHandler.insertObjects(DatastorePersistenceHandler.java:272)
    at org.datanucleus.store.appengine.DatastorePersistenceHandler.insertObject(DatastorePersistenceHandler.java:256)
    at org.datanucleus.state.JDOStateManagerImpl.internalMakePersistent(JDOStateManagerImpl.java:3185)
    at org.datanucleus.state.JDOStateManagerImpl.makePersistent(JDOStateManagerImpl.java:3161)
    at org.datanucleus.ObjectManagerImpl.persistObjectInternal(ObjectManagerImpl.java:1298)
    at org.datanucleus.sco.SCOUtils.validateObjectForWriting(SCOUtils.java:1476)
    at org.datanucleus.store.mapped.scostore.ElementContainerStore.validateElementForWriting(ElementContainerStore.java:380)
    at org.datanucleus.store.mapped.scostore.FKListStore.validateElementForWriting(FKListStore.java:609)
    at org.datanucleus.store.mapped.scostore.FKListStore.internalAdd(FKListStore.java:344)
    at org.datanucleus.store.appengine.DatastoreFKListStore.internalAdd(DatastoreFKListStore.java:146)
    at org.datanucleus.store.mapped.scostore.AbstractListStore.add(AbstractListStore.java:105)
    at org.datanucleus.sco.backed.List.add(List.java:649)
    at (my servlet)
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like an App Engine error was preventing me from uploading the code. Once GAE caught up and switched over to the new code, it all worked fine.

For the record, I'm not sure what fixed it - it may have been just adding the `@Persistent` annotation, or it may have been changing `Published.id` to be a `Key` instead of a `Long`.

Comment: List is default persistent FWIW, so nothing to do with that